# urlencoding by POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, save

Okay, I'm not really sure what going on.. I haven't touched this stuff in a while so I am clueless. But I am basically trying to save HTML to a file, but for some reason this is what is saved.

```
<table id=\"sectorTableMap\">
```

It shouldn't be doing \" so it should be...

```
<table id="sectorTableMap">
```

So how would I fix this? This is my file which saves the file.

```
$user = strtolower($_POST['user']);
$map = $_POST['map'];
$fileName = 'savedMaps/'.$user.'/'.$_POST["fileName"].'.html';
file_put_contents($fileName,$map);
```

This how it is sent to be saved.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","somePage?t="+Math.random(),true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send('map='+data+'&user='+user+'&fileName='+fileName);
```

Comment: My first guess would be magic quotes - http://www.php.net//manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: How would I disable it? I can't access my php.ini due to server, and my htaccess has nothing like this in it.